# Grouping rectangles in ggalluvial

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm producing a graphic using ggalluvial and want to group my variables on the left.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

data <- tibble(left = c("a","b", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
        right = c("e", "e", "e", "f", "e", "f"),
        values = c(1,2,3,2,3,2),
        group = c("Group 3", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2"))

ggplot(data,
      aes(y = values, axis1 = left, axis2 = right)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = group), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", infer.label = TRUE,
            nudge_x = -.1, fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")
```

This produces the figure below:

[image]

I have coloured the flows based upon their group. But I want to group the left hand side based upon their group. I.e. the new order should be c, b, d, a from top to bottom - rather than alphabetical as default.

I'd be very thankful for help getting to a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `left` as factor with levels in the required order `c("c", "b", "d", "a")`.

```
data$left <- factor(data$left, levels=c("c", "b", "d", "a"))

ggplot(data,
      aes(y = values, axis1 = left, axis2 = right)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = group), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", infer.label = TRUE,
            nudge_x = -.1, fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")
```

[image]